# Variable as a part of variable name in it's declaration? Dealing with chart series

Tags: c#, excel, variables, charts, declaration

Is there a way how can I declare variables in a for loop and using the "int i" as a part of the variable name?

I'm trying to set some adjustments of my excel chart in a for loop and assigning different colours needs different series for each line :|.

I want something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < myMaximum; i++ ) 
{
     Excel.Series series_i+1 = (Excel.Series)mychart.SeriesCollection(i+1);
     series_i+1.Border.Color = mycolors[i];
}
```

Is something like this possible?
I need to do it in for loop because the number of series depends on the number of myMaximum.

Comment: why not just set the Series.Name Property

Comment: @Zigma well if i put the names in array ok but still dunno how to use them in series declaration.. or else I don't think it's possible. And if i put series in array I might have more series than I need. If I don't want to use more than one for loop.

Comment: @cheedep well I was thinking about that but I don't get how can I make a new series without name and add the name in the next step. That ain't possible right? OR I might declare it with some shit name and rename it in the Series.Name? Will it override the name really? :D It sounds too magical to me.

Comment: Dictionary ?? http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/192514/string-int-variable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this loop:

```
for(int i=0; i < myMaximum; i++ ) 
{
     Excel.Series series_i+1 = (Excel.Series)mychart.SeriesCollection(i+1);
     series_i+1.Border.Color = mycolors[i];
}
```

`series_i+1` will live for the scope of the loop *only*, not sure why you need a different name if you stay in the same scope, it doesn't make much sense to have a different variable name that never exits the loop.

This would work just the same way:

```
for(int i=0; i < myMaximum; i++ ) 
{
     mychart.SeriesCollection(i+1).Border.Color = mycolors[i];
}
```

I appologize if I completely missed the point, I've re-read the question a bunch of times.

Comment: I'm not very experienced so I wasn't sure about how the chart series work and so on(I read some basic things about it in msdn lib and somewhere else too). I think this might be good enough for me. Lemme try it :D

Comment: Ok, thank you :). It works like I need. I tend to do things the harder/weirder way than it is actually possible :|.